# JQuery how to difference between a select option with an option selected attribute and a select without a selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm populating multiple `select` with a webservice.
This web service is returning the selected value.

Well, at the moment to render them, I have 2 different `select`

```
<select id='select1'>
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id='select2'>
<option selected="selected" value='A'>Option A</option>
<option value='B'>Option B</option>
</select>
```

Well, the first `select` hasn't any `selected` attribute and the second one has it.

When I execute:

```
$("select1").find("option:selected").val(); //Returns 1
$("select2").find("option:selected").val(); //Returns A
```

How I can identify when the `select` has an option really selected?

Comment: The browser by default select the first option. You can add an empty `<option>` to both `<select>` tags to solve the issue.

Comment: are you trying to check if option has an selected attribute?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes @hasan it's possible know it, thanks to @jlars62 now I know that is possible with `jquery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/) jQuery method to find the `select` that has an `option` with the selected attribute.

```
$("select").has("option[selected]")

$("#select1").has("option[selected]").val() // undefined
$("#select2").has("option[selected]").val() // "A"
```

Comment: It does not return a boolean. It returns a jquery object. On the page I have linked in my answer it states the description as _Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element._

Comment: Yes, you're correct, apologies. Though that makes me wonder - in this instance, why even use `.has()` if you could just make your selector a bit more specific, and skip the additional method?

Comment: No worries at all. The difference between `$("#select2").has("option[selected]")` and `$("#select2 option[selected]")` is the latter returns the option element and the former returns a select element. From what I understood of the OPs question is he wanted to get the select element (I could be wrong).

Comment: That's true, I guess at this point it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `:selected` which looks for the selected *state*, you can look for `[selected]`, which will check for the `selected` attribute.

```js
var $selectedOption = $("#select1 option[selected]");

if ($selectedOption.length) {
    //option selected
    console.log(selectedOption.val() + " selected.");
} else {
    //no option selected
    console.log("Nothing selected.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='select1'>
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id='select2'>
<option selected="selected" value='A'>Option A</option>
<option value='B'>Option B</option>
</select>
```